# How to change the background color in existing ssrs report with Boolean parameter

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I have an issue in SSRS report where I have created a boolean parameter with true, false and now for the report if I select True (Default Value): Report will work in the existing way like for headers it will be blue and rows will be in white and if I select False then rows will be hide but now I need to change the background color from blue to white only when I select for false.

However, if I select parameter as True then it should be in default existing color only and the background color need to be change only in False in White. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the background color property, the parameter could be used in an IIF to choose the color.

```
=IIF(Parameters!TF.Value, "Blue", "White")
```